# Converting a double integral from cartesian to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Question: The integral $$\int\limits_0^3 \int\limits_{|x|}^{\sqrt{18-x^2}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dy\ dx$$

has the following form in polar coordinates

My work so far:

$y=\sqrt{18-x^2} \implies x^2+y^2=18 \implies r^2=18, r=3\sqrt2$

$y=|x|$ **This is where I'm stuck**

$r\sin\theta =|r\cos\theta|$ **does this happen at $\theta=\pi/4$? All I did was graph $y=|x|$ and see that makes a 45 degree angle. What value of $r$ corresponds to that?**

$x=0=r\cos\theta \implies 3\sqrt{2}\cos\theta=0 \implies \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$x=3=r\cos\theta \implies 3\sqrt{2}\cos\theta=3 \implies \theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$

So in polar form does the integral turn into

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{?}^{3\sqrt{2}}r^2drd\theta$$

Again I'm not sure what the lower bound is for $r$ or how I would go about finding that.

Also is the rest of my work correct?

EDIT: picture of graph

[image]

Comment: Since $x\in[0,3]$ you use $|x|=x$.

Comment: Ah okay. So then $r\sin\theta=r\cos\theta$ but how do I solve for what $r$ is? Because all I can see so far is that $1=\tan\theta$ but that doesn't help me find the lower bound for r

Comment: If you draw the region of integration that will help you. Draw vertical lines at $x=0$ and $x=3$. The region of integration lies between those two lines, above the graph of $y=|x|$ and below the graph of $y=\sqrt{18-x^2}$. That should help you solve the mystery of what range of values $r$ takes over the region of integration.

Comment: Ah, so graphing does help me (I edited my question with a picture of the graph) I can see that I want to go from $r=0$ to $r=3\sqrt{2}$ right? Is the rest of my work correct?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a one-half in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, your $r$ values are correct, though.

Comment: Hmm not sure about the 1/2. I thought $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$ and since I have to multiply by $rdrd\theta$ it just becomes $r^2drd\theta$? Or do you mean there needs to be a 1/2 in my bounds for theta?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of something else. Forget about the one-half.

Comment: Ah no worries, thanks again for all of your help. My final answer of $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{3\sqrt{2}} r^{2} dr d\theta$ is correct right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.